How do I make the player stick to a moving platform using pymunk?
I'm building a platformer game using the pymunk physics engine, and pygame for displaying it.
I'm wondering how can I make it so that the player sticks to the moving platform? Right now if I don't follow the platform by moving the player, the player remains on the same spot while standing on the platform, and then falls off when the platform moved away.

My pygame/python Version: pygame 2.6.1 (SDL 2.28.4, Python 3.12.3)
Pymunk version: 6.9.0
This is the code I'm using:
#Pymunk Platformer:
import pygame
import pymunk
import sys
import math

pygame.init()
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('Platformer Game')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

space = pymunk.Space()
space.gravity = (0, 900)  # Gravity pulls objects downwards


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width=30, height=30):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((30, 30), pygame.SRCALPHA).convert_alpha()
        self.image.fill((255, 0, 0))  # Red square for player
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(x, y))

        # Pymunk physics body
        mass = 1
        self.width, self.height = width, height
        # inertia = pymunk.moment_for_box(mass, (width, height))
        # Setting the inertia to infinity makes it so that the rectangle does not rotate when colliding with other objects:
        inertia = float("inf")
        self.body = pymunk.Body(mass, inertia)
        self.body.position = x, y
        self.shape = pymunk.Poly.create_box(self.body, (width, height))
        self.shape.collision_type = 1  # Player collision type
        self.shape.friction = 1
        space.add(self.body, self.shape)
        self.on_ground = False
        self.angle = 0
        self.start_position = (x, y)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.center = self.body.position
        self.angle = math.degrees(self.body.angle)
        if self.body.position.y > 2000:
            self.body.position = self.start_position
            self.body.velocity = (0,0)

    def jump(self):
        if self.on_ground:
            self.body.velocity = (self.body.velocity.x, -300)  # Jump velocity
            self.on_ground = False


class Platform(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.image.fill((0, 255, 0))  # Green rectangle for platforms
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(x, y))

        # Static body for platforms
        self.body = pymunk.Body(body_type=pymunk.Body.STATIC)
        self.body.position = x + width / 2, y + height / 2  # Center of the platform
        shape = pymunk.Poly.create_box(self.body, (width, height))
        shape.collision_type = 2  # Platform collision type
        shape.friction = 0.5
        space.add(self.body, shape)

    def update(self):
        pass  # Platforms don't need to update their position


class MovingPlatform(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, range, speed):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.image.fill((0, 255, 0))  # Green rectangle for platforms
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(x, y))

        # Change to KINEMATIC instead of STATIC
        self.body = pymunk.Body(body_type=pymunk.Body.KINEMATIC)
        self.body.position = x+width/2, y+height/2  # Center of the platform
        self.shape = pymunk.Poly.create_box(self.body, (width, height))
        self.shape.collision_type = 2  # Platform collision type
        self.shape.friction = 1.5
        space.add(self.body, self.shape)

        self.range = range  # How far it moves
        self.speed = speed  # Speed of movement
        self.direction = 1  # 1 for moving right/up, -1 for left/down
        self.start_x, self.start_y = x, y

    def update(self):
        # Move the platform back and forth
        if self.body.position.x > self.start_x + self.range and self.direction == 1:
            self.direction = -1  # Reverse direction at edges
        if self.body.position.x < self.start_x and self.direction == -1:
            self.direction = 1  # Reverse direction at edges
        self.body.position = (self.body.position.x + self.direction * self.speed, self.body.position.y)# Set surface velocity to match platform movement
        self.shape.surface_velocity = (self.direction * self.speed, 0)

        self.rect.center = self.body.position


def player_on_ground(arbiter, space, data):
    for shape in arbiter.shapes:
        if shape == player.shape:
            player.on_ground = True
            return True
    return False

handler = space.add_collision_handler(1, 2)  # Player and Platform
handler.begin = player_on_ground

# Create player and platforms
player = Player(350, 200)
platforms = pygame.sprite.Group()
for _ in range(3):  # Create three platforms
    platforms.add(Platform(100 + _ * 200, HEIGHT - 200, 100, 20))
for i in range(2):
    platforms.add(Platform(20 + i * 300, HEIGHT - 300, 200, 20))
for i in range(2):
    ptfm = MovingPlatform(200 + i * 200, HEIGHT - 370, 40, 20, range=100, speed=1)
    platforms.add(ptfm)

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group(*platforms)
direction = "right"
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        player.body.velocity = (-150, player.body.velocity.y)  # Move left
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        player.body.velocity = (150, player.body.velocity.y)  # Move right
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        player.jump()

    # Update physics
    space.step(1 / 60.0)

    # Update sprites
    all_sprites.update()
    player.update()

    # Draw
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(player.image, player.angle)
    width, height = rotated_image.get_size()
    half_width, half_height = int(width/2), int(height/2)
    x, y = player.rect.center
    screen.blit(rotated_image, [x - half_width, y - half_height])
    # print(player.body.position)

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()


It is a bit tricky to get the right feeling.
First thing is you should set the velocity of the platform. Otherwise it will behave as if it teleports around. Even if it can be worked around for the player case, its better to do it from the beginning I thin if there's other things you add later.
Then you can adjust the surface velocity to be the same as the platform velocity. I see you already do this, but the problem is it doesnt adjust for the time step. Each physics loop is 1/60s long in your code (often called dt, or delta time). To get velocity, you should use the difference in position multiplied with the dt:
old_position = self.body.position

# ... the code to set position

self.body.velocity = (self.body.position - old_position) * 60.0
# or if you want to use the same calculation as you used to set position:
self.body.velocity = self.direction * self.speed * 60, 0
self.shape.surface_velocity = self.body.velocity

As a side note, you update pygame frame 50 times a second, but you pass 1/60 of a second to pymunk.step. I think you want to align so you either use 60 and 1/60 or 50 and 1/50. :)

Thanks for the input. You are correct about the delta time and FPS. This is merely a quick demonstration to showcase what I'm trying to do, with the player moving on the platform (for which dt is irrelevant). In my final project I will implement it as you say. I will check to change the velocity as you say.

Regarding your suggestion to change the body's velocity, when I change that, why does it not automatically change the position of the body? If the velocity increases, the body should change positions and move right?

Not sure I follow what you mean. Yes, if you set the velocity the position will update. However, the position will update during the simulation step (when space.step is called), not exactly at the time you set the velocity.

You could attach a boolean to the Player that determines whether the Player is "on a moving platform" or not. Maybe you could call it "onMovePlatform".
You could use PyMunk's CollisionHandler class (https://www.pymunk.org/en/latest/pymunk.html#pymunk.CollisionHandler) to detect whether or not the player is on a MovePlatform object, or in this case, if the Player is "colliding" with the MovePlatform object. So when the Player "collides" with the MovePlatform, you can set: "onMovePlatform = True"
If the program sees that "onMovePlatform == True", you can make it so that every time the MovePlatform's position changes, you use the same change to the MovePlatform and apply it to the Player position as well. Like if MovePlatform is moving 5 to the right every frame, you add 5 to the right for the Player as well. Same applies to the other direction(s), and vice versa.
Then when you press Space to jump, you can automatically set onMovePlatform = false since you can assume that since you are now in mid air, you are no longer in contact with the MovePlatform object, and since the boolean is now set to false, it no longer applies the transformation to the player's position.
